# Java pass by value is really working?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, pass-by-value

I have a doubt here.
I am learning Java and I see a behavior that I don't understand.
I read java in pass by value and the original variable shouldn't change its values when you send it to a method (or that is what I understood so far).

So, I will add here two cases that are very alike in my point of view.
First case the variable doesn't change its value.
Second case, the variable changes it's value.

### **First Case (Variable stays the same way):**

```
package Chapter10.Part6;

import java.util.Scanner;


// Important: Pass by Value!

public class Chap10Part6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int number;

        System.out.print("Enter a Interger: ");
        number = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Number squared: " + square(number));
        System.out.println("Original Number: " + number);


        input.close();

    }


    static int square(int num){
        num = num * num;
        System.out.println("Number in square method: " + num);
        return num;


    }
}
```

### **Second Case (Variable changes):**

```
package Chapter15.Part4;

import Chapter15.FunctionsPart1;

public class Chap15Part4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int rows = 10;
        final int columns = 5;
        int [][] table = new int[rows][columns];

        FunctionsPart1.build2DArray(table, rows, columns);
        FunctionsPart1.display2DArray(table, rows, columns);


        System.out.println("");
        FunctionsPart1.organize2DArray(table, rows, columns);
        FunctionsPart1.display2DArray(table, rows, columns);
   }
}



package Chapter15;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class FunctionsPart1 {


    public static void build2DArray(int[][] arr, int rows, int columns){
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                arr[i][j] = rand.nextInt(101);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void display2DArray(int[][] arr, int rows, int columns){
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
                if((j+1)%columns == 0)
                    System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }


    public static void organize2DArray(int[][] table, int rows, int columns){
        int t = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < columns; y++)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                    {
                        if(table[i][j] > table[x][y])
                        {
                            t = table[x][y];
                            table[x][y] = table[i][j];
                            table[i][j] = t;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Could anyone explain me why?

Thanks for the time.

Comment: The variable is passed by value. The content of the variable is a reference to an array. The array itself is not copied. So it is possible it to find that it is modified by a receiving function.

Comment: In short, arrays are treated as objects when they are passed to a method. Objects are passing the value of the reference. Though invoking or working on this reference will reflect in changes to the original object.

Comment: The `table` variable doesn't change.  In neither example does the variable change. You might be changing the data the `table` points to, but this is not the same as changing the variable.

Comment: Thanks everyone who answered me.